# Java/Python Communication through RabbitMQ

Tags: java, python, rabbitmq, messaging

I want to develop a messaging application using java as producer and python as consumer of the message through RabbitMQ. Please suggest how can I do this. Thanks for your suggestions and comments.

Comment: Google says there is a module called pika for building python clients for rabbitmq available via pip. Also plenty of tutorials how to do this.

Comment: Thanks @barrios, I was looking for some solution where I can compile both .Java and .py under one workspace using Jython (may be/not sure) and usage of STOMP for multi-platform communication. Anyways, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Let me read the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) for you.

**reciever.py**

```
import pika

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(body)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='some_queue')

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='some_queue',
                      no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

**sender.java**

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Send {
   private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "some_queue";

   public static void main(String[] argv) throws java.io.IOException {
      ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
      factory.setHost("localhost");
      Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
      Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
      channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);

      String message = "Hello World!";
      channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());

      channel.close();
      connection.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergey,  I was looking for some solution where I can compile both .Java and .py under one workspace using Jython (may be/not sure) and usage of STOMP for multi-platform communication. Anyways, thanks for your effort.